# How to clone a static class in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, object, ecmascript-6

I have a model mock that I want to reuse like so:

```
// simplified
class ModelMock {
    static async findOneAndUpdate() {

    }
    static async findOne() {

    }
    async save() {

    }
  }
```

but need to mock them individually per the model such as

```
const models = {
  User: ModelMock,
  Business: ModelMock
}
```

but I really want each mock class to be its own thing without having to resort to prototypal syntax or duplicating code.

The reason being in testing...

```
sinon.mock(MockModule.prototype).expects('save').resolves({ specific: 'thing' })
```

won't work as I have to have a specific class for each model then and also the static methods are shared of course.

**Notice both static and instance methods**

How do I do that?

Comment: If you want each one to be its own thing than why aren't you using "new ModelMock" so that your save() methods are unique for each instance?

const models = {
  User: new ModelMock,
  Business: new ModelMock
}

Comment: @nopuck4you the model needs to have both static and instance methods as it can be newed by the client code and is also used statically at the same time

Comment: You should never have a `class` with only static methods. Use an object literal instead.

Comment: @Bergi it has both actually but I'm mocking an external class such as mongoose for example so I don't have the luxury of deciding implementation details in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Class factory seems to work in this case

I resorted to doing a class factory like so:

```
function getModelMock() {
  return class {
    static async findOneAndUpdate() {

    }
    static async findOne() {

    }
    async save() {

    }
  }
}
```

as you can use like so:

```
const models = {
  Business: getModelMock(),
  User: getModelMock()
}

sinon.mock(models.Business.prototype).expects('save').resolves({ _id: 'businessId' })
sinon.mock(models.Business).expects('findOne').resolves({ _id: 'businessId' })
sinon.mock(models.User.prototype).expects('save').resolves({ _id: 'userId' })
```

as you can anonymously make a class without stating its name which I thought was interesting but are there better ways to do this with an actual clone if you cannot make a factory?

Answer (score 1):

This answer is intentionally a detailed "I don't think you can", in an effort to help others who are trying to do the same thing understand why I concluded that it's not possible, at least [not without `eval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#never_use_eval!) and maybe not even then. I have a fairly deep understanding of Javascript's prototypical class implementation, but there are many who have deeper knowledge than me.

#### My Requirements

I came here with the question stated in this post, and also ended up settling for a class factory. My requirement was that the cloned class is identical to one obtained with a class factory. Specifically, I want a function such that this:

```
class Parent {}
class Child extends Parent {}
const Sibling = cloneClass(Child)
```

results in the exact same state as this:

```
class Parent {}
function classFactory() {
  return class Child extends Parent {}
}
const Child = classFactory()
const Sibling = classFactory()
```

Things that are thus dealbreakers for my purposes:

- A `Sibling` that is an instance of or prototypically descended from `Child` (its first prototype should be `Parent`)
- A `Sibling` that shares a prototype or function definitions with `Child`

For my needs, it is useful if `Sibling.name == Child.name == 'Child'`, which is the case in the class-factory setup.

Technically to be exactly the same there are more requirements (`Sibling`'s methods can't be prototypically descended from `Child`'s methods, for instance), but I think that is moot, for reasons that will soon become apparent.

#### The sticky bits

The thing that makes this impossible by my reckoning is actually quite simple: it requires cloning functions, and you can't do that. There are a [couple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1833588/javascript-clone-a-function) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/447658/can-i-copy-clone-a-function-in-javascript) about it here, which have various solutions that work in some cases but are not actually cloning, and don't fulfill my requirements. For what it's worth, functions are on lodash's list of "[uncloneable values](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#clone)" as well.

This is relevant for class methods, but more crucially, it is relevant because under the hood, classes *are* functions. In a very literal sense, a class *is* its constructor function. Thus, even if you could deal with class methods that are prototypically descended from `Child`'s methods, I think you can't get around the fact that that also means that the `Sibling` class itself - which is a function - will also have to be prototypically descended from `Child`.

Edit: See below, if `Child` doesn't have a constructor function, then you may be able to skirt around this requirement.

#### Other thoughts/caveats

I'm happy to be proven wrong here, or have my understanding corrected, but I think that is the central blocker here: classes are functions, and you can't clone a function.

One route I haven't pursued, because it is darker magic than I am willing to delve into, is using the `Function()` constructor to almost-but-not-quite-eval yourself into a truly "cloned" function. I am not sure if this is possible, and I am not knowledgeable enough of the implications of doing so to try.

#### Requirements Demo

If you want to have a go at it, I made a snippet that has a few tests that assert my requirements - if you can get my requirements passing with a clone function, do let me know!

Edit: @Bergi offered up a solution that I've included in the snippet below. It does seem to do the job! I believe it gets around the problem of cloning the constructor by...not doing so, since in my case the child classes don't *have* their own constructor. Thus an empty function (with everything else tacked on) is indeed equivalent to a clone. It also comes with all the standard disclaimers around [using setPrototype](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/setPrototypeOf).

```js
'use strict'
let hadWarning = false
const getProto = Object.getPrototypeOf

class Parent {}
function classFactory () {
  return class Child extends Parent {}
}

function factoryTest () {
  const Child = classFactory()
  const Sibling = classFactory()

  runTest(Child, Sibling, 'classFactory')
}

/* Adapted from @Bergi */

function cloneClass (Target, Source) {
  return Object.defineProperties(
    Object.setPrototypeOf(
      Target,
      Object.getPrototypeOf(Source)
    ),
    {
      ...Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(Source),
      prototype: {
        value: Object.create(
          Object.getPrototypeOf(Source.prototype),
          Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(Source.prototype)
        )
      }
    }
  )
}

function berghiTest () {
  class Child extends Parent {}
  const Sibling = cloneClass(function Sibling () {}, Child)

  runTest(Child, Sibling, 'Bergi\'s clone')
}

factoryTest()
berghiTest()

/* Assertion support */
function fail (message, warn) {
  if (warn) {
    hadWarning = true
    console.warn(`Warning: ${message}`)
  } else {
    const stack = new Error().stack.split('\n')
    throw new Error(`${message} ${stack[3].trim()}`)
  }
}

function assertEqual (expected, actual, warn) {
  if (expected !== actual) {
    fail(`Expected ${actual} to equal ${expected}`, warn)
  }
}
function assertNotEqual (expected, actual, warn) {
  if (expected === actual) {
    fail(`Expected ${actual} to not equal ${expected}`, warn)
  }
}

function runTest (Child, Sibling, testName) {
  Child.classTag = 'Child'
  Sibling.classTag = 'Sibling'

  hadWarning = false

  assertEqual(Child.name, 'Child')
  assertEqual(Sibling.name, Child.name, true) // Maybe not a hard requirement, but nice
  assertEqual(Child.classTag, 'Child')
  assertEqual(Sibling.classTag, 'Sibling')

  assertEqual(getProto(Child).name, 'Parent')
  assertEqual(getProto(Sibling).name, 'Parent')
  assertEqual(getProto(Child), Parent)
  assertEqual(getProto(Sibling), Parent)

  assertNotEqual(Child.prototype, Sibling.prototype)
  assertEqual(getProto(Child.prototype), Parent.prototype)
  assertEqual(getProto(Sibling.prototype), Parent.prototype)

  const child = new Child()
  const sibling = new Sibling()

  assertEqual(sibling instanceof Child, false)
  assertEqual(child instanceof Parent, true)
  assertEqual(sibling instanceof Parent, true)

  if (hadWarning) {
    console.log(`${testName} passed (with warnings)`)
  } else {
    console.log(`${testName} passed!`)
  }
}
```

Comment: How "*exactly the same state*" do you need it? Do you expect `Sibling.toString() === Child.toString()`? Otherwise it's easily possible to create a new function that does the same as some existing function. And what about  `Sibling.prototype.someMethod === Child.prototype.someMethod` - do you care whether they are the same or not?

Comment: Good points. You would have to resort to a bunch of factories for unclonable things I think.

Comment: I've edited a bit above - class/instance methods being inherited and/or copies of each other is maybe fine, as long as they have the right `this` context, of course. My main concern is the prototype chain, because things outside my control make assumptions that `Sibling` is directly descended from `Parent`.

Comment: `Object.defineProperties( Object.setPrototypeOf( function Sibling() {}, Object.getPrototypeOf(Child) ), { ...Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(Child), prototype: {value: Object.create( Object.getPrototypeOf(Child.prototype), Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(Child.prototype) )} } );` does pass your test (SCNR to make it a oneliner :P)

Comment: Oh dang, so it does! Okay, yeah that'd do it...if I'm reading correctly, I think this depends on the child classes not having their own constructor, correct? And thus you don't actually have to clone the constructor, because an empty function is equivalent? I've included your method as a `cloneClass()` method in my snippet, but feel free to post it as its own answer too

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use a factory function, you could use `new`:

```
const models = {
  User: new ModelMock(),
  Business: new ModelMock()
};
```

Comment: The ModelMock is used with static methods and instance methods which is the caveat. I updated description to be more clear. Thanks.

Comment: @JasonSebring Static methods can (generally) be accessed by using `this.constructor.foo`